# Rename a file in unix to include $ sign (ie a java class file)

Tags: file, unix, creation

I have a java class file that is causing problems because of the length of the name:

GroundTransportationProductType$GroundTransportationOptions$GroundTransportationProductOption$GroundTransportationOptionProviderLinks$ProviderLinks.class

I have managed to get the file on the unix box (Solaris) by under a shortend file name.
my.class

How can I rename my.class to the correct class name above?

Using mv and cp normally (ie not doing something for the dollar signs) does not work.
I have googled and searched extensively but cannot find anything on how to create a file with a dollar name in it on unix.

Thanks,

Kenny

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$` has a special meaning in shells, so you need to escape it somehow. The best option would be to use single quotes around your filenames. A \ in front of the '$' sign would also work.

```
mv my.class 'Long$File$Name.class'
```

or

```
mv my.class Long\$File\$Name.class
```

Comment: Perfect thanks, I used the single quote.